# Without definition of "square" why this function slower?

Tags: scheme, sicp

This question is located in SICP(Exercise 1.26)
It says that without the definition of "square",it runs slower.
It aims to checking whether the number is a prime.
This is the quicker version:

[Scheme,Prime check,*O*(log *n*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiNZj.jpg)

Without definition of "square",use

```
(* (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)
   (expmod base (/ exp 2) m))
```

It is said to be *O*(*n*)

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `square` procedure that makes it faster but the caching of the intermediate value. Using `let` would make it just as fast:

```
(let ((tmp (expmod base (/ exp 2) m))) 
  (* tmp tmp))
```

The key point is that `(expmod base (/ exp 2) m)` is only done one time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate `(expmod base (/ exp 2) m)` twice if you don't use `square`. If you bind the result with `let` and pass it to `square`, then it'd be the same complexity.